# No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional

Tags: hibernate

Hi i am new to spring + hiberent i am trying to wirte GenericDao but i got following exception  No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional  see my code

**IGenericDao**

```
public interface IGenericDao<T> {
    public void delete(T obj);
    public void saveOrUpdate(T obj);
}
```

**GenericDaoImpl**

```
  @Transactional
  public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("SessionFactory has not been set on DAO before usage");
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(T obj) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(obj);
    }
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }
}
```

**IGenericService**

```
public interface IGenericService<T extends Object> {
    public void delete(T obj);
    public void saveOrUpdate(T obj);

}
```

**IGenericServiceManagerImpl**

```
public  class IGenericServiceManagerImpl<T extends Object> implements  IGenericService<T>  {

@Autowired
IGenericDao<T> genericDao;
@Override

public void delete(T obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    genericDao.delete(obj);
}

@Override

public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    genericDao.saveOrUpdate(obj);

}
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

       ">

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>


    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>

            <value>com.codes.gdi.model.EMP</value>


        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" />


    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://spring:myinstance/gdirectorystaging" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

AnyOne help me
I got    No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `<context:component-scan base-package="pathToScan" />`

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html
(4.12.2)

Answer (score 0):

About your configuration you are totally missing dao/service bean definition and your are not enabling annotation driven transaction adding `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to XML (remember to add `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd`).

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">
```

If DAO code will still not work with Hibernate3 use `HibernateTemplate` in this manner

```
public class GenericDaoImpl extends HibernateTemplate implements IGenericDao{
  @Override
  public void delete(T obj) {
    getSession().delete(obj);
  }
}
```

If you are using Hibernate4 leave DAO code unchanged, but change bean class according to new class (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`) and use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` to build sessionFactory.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help i am trying to add but i got Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems 
 View and select "Show Details..."